# ELB targeting EC2 in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to setup an EC2 instance in private subnet which will be accessible through ELB, which in turn is in public subnet. I created VPC having 2 private (us-east-1a, us-east-1b AZs) and two public (us-east-1a, us-east-1b AZs) subnets. EC2 is in private subnet as mentioned, its security group allows access from ELB sec group
[image]
[image]

All public subnets associated with ELB are in same AZ as their respective private counterparts.

Load balancer has egress rule in place to reach EC2 instance.

But still, the instance is marked as unhealthy, ELB can not reach EC2.
[image]

My networking skills are quite poor, I'm lost and don't know where to look. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Launching EC2 in public subnet works just fine. ELB is able to access webserver without an issue. Launching in private subnet somehow breaks everything

Comment: Are you sure your web app is working correctly in a private subnet? Did you check if its working?

Comment: It is an Elastic Beanstalk provisioned instance through CDK. Under public subnet it works as usual, under private, I can't reach it and have no clue how to test this. But I assume it does as the only change between the previous two deployments were EC2 subnet

Comment: But is your eb in a private instance working? Did you actually verify if the app is working and crashing due to being in a private subnet?

Comment: It looks like you have allowed access from everywhere (source 0.0.0.0/0 + all ports) anyway. But Is the security group in question actually the instance's security group. I couldn't see that in the pictures you shared.

Comment: Hey Marcin. You were actually right, I managed to test SSH (22) and HTTP (80) ports, 22 was accessible, 80 was not. So it seems Beanstalk doesn't start the application when its in private subnet for some reason. I even downloaded AWS app sample from their docs site. thanks for the hint. pls write your suggestion as answer so I can accept it

Comment: Please add references to the specifications for the things you do (for each part) and highlight where your expectation does not meet that specification. Otherwise it's about running a system and that's OT I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Beanstalk EC2 instance should be placed either in public subnet or private subnet with NAT gateway. Isolated private subnets are not supported as EC2 needs to talk to Beanstalk API which are external AWS resources.

Source https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/evhbwx/comment/ffwxnmg/